# Filter DataFrame after sklearn.feature_selection

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

I reduce dimensionality of a dataset (pandas DataFrame).

```
X = df.as_matrix()
sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=0.1)
X_r = sel.fit_transform(X)
```

then I wanto to get back the reduced DataFrame (i.e. keep only ok columns)

I found only this ugly way to do so, which is very inefficient, do you have any cleaner idea?

```
    cols_OK = sel.get_support()  # which columns are OK?
    c = list()
    for i, col in enumerate(cols_OK):
        if col:
            c.append(df.columns[i])
    return df[c]
```

Comment: It seems need `df = df.loc[:, sel.get_support()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need if return `mask`:

```
cols_OK = sel.get_support()
df = df.loc[:, cols_OK]
```

and if return indices:

```
cols_OK = sel.get_support()
df = df.iloc[:, cols_OK]
```